# Matlab result as animation in Beamer

Tags: beamer, matlab, animations

Some pdfteX slides include some matlab plots as animation using a window like the following

[image]

using which, one is able to go forward and backward, pause, or and change the speed. I would like to know which package can be used to make such animations? Can you provide me with a short functioning example of including results from Matlab into an animation in Beamer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for Per Bergström's AnimatedLaTeX package. It can be found [in Matlab File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17813-animatelatex) along with many examples both in Matlab and LaTeX.